# include does not work with local data store?

Tags: parse-platform

```
ParseQuery<Custom> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Custom.class);
query.whereEqualTo("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
query.include("address");
query.fromLocalDatastore();
query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<Custom>() {
    @Override
    public void done(Custom c, ParseException e) {
         c.getAddress().getName(); //this gives me fetchIfneeded exception.
    }
});
```

if I do something like this

```
ParseQuery<Address> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Address.class);
query.fromLocalDatastore();
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Address>() {
    @Override
     public void done(List<Address> addresses, ParseException e) {
         for(Address address: addresses) {
             address.getName(); //it works just fine   
         }           
     }
 });
```

looks like the include does not work with local datastore.
is this by design? or miss something?

edit:
I can survive by adding

```
c.getAddress().fetchFromLocalDatastore();
```

Comment: is Custom.class a Parse Subclass?

Comment: yes, it is. I can pin, unpin, saveEventually without any problem.